# Issues Applying Enemy AI SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, artificial-intelligence

I am attempting to create a zombie game in sprite kit using swift. In my game, at the beginning, I add 5 zombies using a for loop. Here is the code for adding the zombies.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var zombie = SKSpriteNode()
    var spawnPoint1 = CGPointMake(1450, 311)
    var spawnPoint2 = CGPointMake(1968, 406)
    var spawnPoint3 = CGPointMake(1323, 470)
    var mediumZombieMoveSpeed: CGFloat = 2

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    for var b = 0; b < 5; b++ {
        createZombie()
    }
    }

func createZombie() {
    var randomModel = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomPoint = arc4random_uniform(3)


    if randomModel == 0 {
        zombie = SKSpriteNode(texture: zombieTexM1)
        if randomPoint == 0 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint1
        }
        else if randomPoint == 1 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint2
        }
        else {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint3
        }

        zombie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(32, 32))
        zombie.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        zombie.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        zombie.name = "zombie"


        world?.addChild(zombie)

    }
    else if randomModel == 1 {
        zombie = SKSpriteNode(texture: zombieTexM2)

        if randomPoint == 0 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint1
        }
        else if randomPoint == 1 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint2
        }
        else {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint3
        }
        zombie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(32, 32))
        zombie.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        zombie.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        zombie.name = "zombie"

        world?.addChild(zombie)

    }
    else if randomModel == 2 {
        zombie = SKSpriteNode(texture: zombieTexM3)
        if randomPoint == 0 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint1
        }
        else if randomPoint == 1 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint2
        }
        else {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint3
        }
        zombie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(32, 32))
        zombie.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        zombie.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        zombie.name = "zombie"
        world?.addChild(zombie)

    }
    else if randomModel == 3 {
        zombie = SKSpriteNode(texture: zombieTexM4)
        if randomPoint == 0 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint1
        }
        else if randomPoint == 1 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint2
        }
        else {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint3
        }



        world?.addChild(zombie)

    }
    else {
        zombie = SKSpriteNode(texture: zombieTexM5)
        if randomPoint == 0 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint1
        }
        else if randomPoint == 1 {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint2
        }
        else {
            zombie.position = spawnPoint3
        }
        zombie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(32, 32))
        zombie.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        zombie.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        world?.addChild(zombie)
    }
}
    }
```

And here is the code in the update method that is supposed to be the zombie AI.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if player.position.x < zombie.position.x && overrideWalkRight == false {
        zombie.position.x -= mediumZombieMoveSpeed
    }
    else if player.position.x > zombie.position.x {
        zombie.position.x += mediumZombieMoveSpeed
    }
    if player.position.y - 35  > zombie.position.y && player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy == 0 && noJump == false {
        zombie.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 5))
    }

    if zombie.position.x > 170 && zombie.position.x < 1005 && zombie.position.y > player.position.y && zombie.position.y > 360 {
        overrideWalkRight = true
    }
    else {
        overrideWalkRight = false
    }
    if player.position.x > 170 && player.position.x < 965 && player.position.y > zombie.position.y && zombie.position.y < 370 && zombie.position.y > 278 {
        noJump = true
    }

    else {
        noJump = false
    }

    }
```

The AI itself works perfectly. However, the for loop in the didMoveToView method adds five zombies to the scene. The AI only works for the first zombie. I am trying to figure out a way for the AI to work for every zombie that is added to the scene. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are adding the zombies to an `SKNode` called `world`. If so, you can loop over the `children` of `world` in `update`. You can add the hero to another a different `SKNode` so only the zombies are affected in update.

Comment: @0x141E I need the hero in world because that is how I have the camera following the player. I also need the zombies in world. All of the zombies appear but only one of them works

Comment: You can create another `SKNode` called `zombies`, add all the zombies to that node, and add `zombies` to `world`.